# alert who is already reading this page in php?

Tags: php, alert

We have a back end application to manage messages from our clients. We have 4 customer care executives and we want to prevent the situation where the same message can't be opened by two different members, so we would like to do following...

Suppose user1 opened message id 15 and after that user2 opens same message, so we would like to give a alert that 'This message is already opened by user1'. How do we do it?

Comment: It looks like you should hire programmer to do that... I just can tell that it will involve database transactions, row-locking etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a different table in your database.
When a user opens a message, update the table to show which message has been opened and by which user.

When another user tries to open it, crosscheck the table to see if there is a row for that message. You can then do the appropriate action such as open or warn the user.

You can delete the rows after a given timeout period to allow others to open.

Schema eg

```
 
User_id   msg_id  time_opened
```

---

Unfortunately, you can't use sessions since the sesssion is user specific. However, you can employ flatfiles.

To delete the rows, employ a method such as

```
 

$timeout_time_in_seconds = 30;
$time = time() - $timeout_time_in_seconds; 
$Query= "delete from table where time_opened
```

Note that depending on the time field, which can be an int, datetime or timestring, additional date formating of the $time variable may be required. However, int will be most convenient due to ease in comparison and subtraction and no formatting.

I'm mobile so pardon any errors. Also that's why I didn't comment but had to edit. Js issues.

---

What happens is, when the first user clicks, a quick check and update of the database is made. 
When the second user tries, the script will detect the first user has already opened by checking the database.

You can count on this to work if the traffic load is low and the number of users trying to access is not too great. And also counting on the fact that the read and insert queries occur in a short time which as you can Guess is faster then two users clicking at the same time. Unless you have another issue, this should work

Comment: thakns for great help, is there any other way to achieve this like using session or something else.

Comment: and how can we delete the rows after a given timeout period?

Comment: thanks for great support, but there is a problem, like what if 2 users clicks at same message at same time then how it will work? i hope question makes sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

Simpliest way would be to implement as pessimistic locking at the DB level
http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/PessimisticLocking.aspx
Whatever language you are using should let you check the DB to see if a row is locked or not and send a message on the screen.

You can additionally setup your application with long polling to notify users when the request resource has become available. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

Comment: First off in mySql you'll need to use InnoDB to implement row level locking http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-lock-modes.html then depending on your programming language how you check for the locks. Just google it and something should come up.

Comment: @ali is there any simpler method to achieve this? like using session or something.

Comment: Well you could set a boolean value in your table that says 'opened' and if this value is set to true then alert the user saying that the particular item is already open. The trouble here is that a user may not close the page properly, or his browser may crash permanently marking that record as opened. To prevent this you'll have to add a 'timeout' feature which would involve having the browser call a page every 5 minutes or so using ajax and the page would keep incrementing the timeout time for the opened record. Make sense? If I'm helpful please feel free to vote up the answer.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are using PHP from your other posts. Its not something I can throw together, it will have to be thought out because there is the front-end polling part to it as well. Here is an even easier version that occured to me. When a user opens a record, insert their username against that record. Then as long as that username is there, only allow that user to open and edit the file. When the user closes the file (properly) then set the username against that record to null or empty or some other value. This way when an other user accesses a record, allow if 'editing_user' is null

Comment: else if 'editing_user' is not null, prompt saying something like "User XYZ has opened this file, User XYZ must close the file before editing is allowed". I hope you can code this on your own. In this case display a read-only version of the form.